# ruby require does not load variable - undefined local variable

Tags: ruby

Have an external file, `wordlist.rb`, that contains

```
code_words = { 'a' => 'is a', 'b' => 'is b' }
```

This file is stored in the same directory that contains my code
require '`wordlist`'

```
code_word.each do | mykey, mysentence | puts mykey + "=> " mysentence end
```

when I run this code, I get the following message

```
<main>': undefined local variable or method code_words' for main:Object (NameError)
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You should have a global variable(i.e. starting with a `$`) to be able to access it from a file that you require.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a local variable. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in. That's why they are called *local* variables. You cannot access another scope's local variables, that's the whole point of local variables.

If you want the variable to be in global scope, you need to use a global variable.

However, in this case, it looks like you actually want a global constant, not a variable at all:

```
CODE_WORDS = { 'a' => 'is a', 'b' => 'is b' }

puts CODE_WORDS.map {|mykey, mysentence| "#{mykey} => #{mysentence}" }.join("\n")
```